# how can I get DeviceID, serial number of chromebook in javascript

Tags: system-information, chromebook

I need to develop an Packaged App which could get and print deviceID, SerialNumber and other system information of Chromebook in javascript.
If we can run shell command:
 run `sudo dump_vpd_log --full –stdout`
and retrieve information from it in javascript.

Thanks

Comment: I understand javascript runs under sand-boxed environment of browser and can not access system resources. otherwise If I have to identify ChromeBook then How can I do that. Like can I generate uuid of ChromeBook.